# How can I populate an ImageSwitcher from a url list? (EDIT: Horizontal RecyclerView)

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, android-recyclerview

I have an object which includes a list of strings. These are urls to pictures and I'm using Picasso library to set in ImageView. I would like to set these images in an ImageSwitcher, and I dont know how to do it (I've done some researches before but no results). Thanks for helping guys !

EDIT : 
I finally chose a Horizontal RecyclerView to have a Gallery like, so in my layout for a row there's only an ImageView. I also have now a Recycler Adapter but i dont know if i have to include my list of strings in the adapter, or just handle the imageView and create dynamically an ImageView and add it to the recycler list in my java class.... Thanks for helping !

Comment: You can [pass the URI](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_imageswitcher.htm) to the ImageSwitcher directly. If you insist of using Picasso, you probably need to build a `Drawable` from the loaded image and use that in `setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, problem is, that there's an image given every time. I would like to give all my list. Size is variable, so will be the imageswitcher.

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be a Rx approach. I'm not really versed in Rx so I can't develop the idea more

Comment: Thanks for ur comment, I think that I can do it in an easier way. Otherwise, maybe is it better to do a horizontal scrollview ? But i dont know how to create an imageview dynamically in that  view.. Advices are welcome for the choice, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Adapter` should have a constructor in which you will pass the urls as a parameter to the `Adapter`. Your `Adapter` will look something like this:

```
public class ImageSwitcherAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageSwitcherAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> urls;

    public ImageSwitcherAdapter(Context context, List<String> urls) {
        this.context = context;
        this.urls = urls;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_row_layout, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(urls.get(position));
        Picasso.with(context).load(uri).into(holder.image);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return urls.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView image;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.your_imageview);
        }
    }
}
```

And setting the `Adapter` to your `RecyclerView` will look something like this:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.your_recyclerview);

LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

ImageSwitcherAdapter adapter = new ImageSwitcherAdapter(this, urls);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks ! It worked, I just didn't need to do a Uri parse while using Picasso, it can directly take a string to load the image ! :)