# in Recycler view item Multiple url load on single image view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso, android-glide

Is there any way to load multiple url in single image view?
I have requirement in List view show multiple image in single image view mean i got a url [] ex: i got url array size 5 then Load image every 1 second with fade in fade out animation in list. every item url[] is diff.
i try picasso and Glide there is no method in multiple url with single imageview.

Comment: use view pager and turn on the sliding automatically every second

Comment: or you can start timer and change image every second to the array size

Comment: Thanks for the advising, but this process is on Recycler-view if i use timer and list size is 100 then timer stuck the app.

Comment: okay , use the timer for current visible items in recycler view , no need to use timer for all items, just find out the current visible items and apply timer or any trick

Comment: may be : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309353/how-can-i-populate-an-imageswitcher-from-a-url-list-edit-horizontal-recyclerv

Comment: https://github.com/saeedsh92/Banner-Slider